# Issue with creating refresh token via HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to implement refresh tokens in our application using the following tutorial:

https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/refreshing-authorization-tokens-angular-6/

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of null
    at HttpAuthInterceptor.push../src/app/Interceptors/newauth.interceptor.ts.HttpAuthInterceptor.intercept (newauth.interceptor.ts:38)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1279)
    at LoaderInterceptor.intercept (loader.interceptor.ts:55)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1279)
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1888)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1279)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1932)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1099)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
```

My code is:

```
import { HttpEvent,HttpHandler,HttpInterceptor,HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../Services/Auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class HttpAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private Route: Router) { }

  inflightAuthRequest = null;

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // exempt some paths from authentication
    if (req.headers.get('authExempt') === 'true') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);

    if (!this.inflightAuthRequest) {
      this.inflightAuthRequest = authService.getToken();
    }

    return this.inflightAuthRequest.pipe(
      switchMap((newToken: string) => {
        // unset request inflight
        this.inflightAuthRequest = null;

        // use the newly returned token
        const authReq = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('token', newToken ? newToken : '')
        });

        // resend the request
        return next.handle(authReq);
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          // check if the response is from the token refresh end point
          const isFromRefreshTokenEndpoint = !!error.headers.get('unableToRefreshToken');

          if (isFromRefreshTokenEndpoint) {
            localStorage.clear();
            this.Route.navigate(['/login']);
            return throwError(error);
          }

          if (!this.inflightAuthRequest) {
            this.inflightAuthRequest = authService.refreshToken();

            if (!this.inflightAuthRequest) {
              // remove existing tokens
              localStorage.clear();
              this.Route.navigate(['/login']);
              return throwError(error);
            }
          }

          return this.inflightAuthRequest.pipe(
            switchMap((newToken: string) => {
              // unset inflight request
              this.inflightAuthRequest = null;

              // clone the original request
              const authReqRepeat = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('token', newToken)
              });

              // resend the request
              return next.handle(authReqRepeat);
            })
          );
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Line 38 in the error is referencing `return this.inflightAuthRequest.pipe(`. I am not sure what I need to do and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: at the beginning of your code I can see that you set the inflightAuthRequest to null which is causing the problem. perhaps try to set it to something that isn't null?

Comment: I see that but the tutorial was pretty specific in setting it to null. Am I missing something because I agree with you?

Comment: @Vega It is there in the code

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this part:

```
if (!this.inflightAuthRequest) {
  this.inflightAuthRequest = authService.getToken();
}
```

After:

```
const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
```

I must have forgotten to include that part in the article, was in the repo though. Sorry about that.

Comment: The getToken method was introduced in your next article but it contains `this.decoder.isTokenExpired(token);` I was hoping to not use the `JwtHelperService` library which is needed for the `decoder` object. How can I to getToken without needing it?

Comment: Please see above

Comment: I ended up using `JwtHelperService` but the app is just hanging now and strangely enough not throwing any errors. It seems like it is stuck in a loop.... Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the adding of the getToken method

Comment: The idea behind the tutorial was to check if a token is expired before sending the request and refreshing it, while at the same time catching expired tokens and refreshing and resending the request. For a simpler version of the same, I would suggest something like [this](https://github.com/mainawycliffe/angular-simple-token-basedauthentication-interceptor/blob/master/httpinteceptorclass.ts). With this, you can replace `const Authorization = authService.getToken();` with something as simple as `const Authorization = "TOKEN HERE"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: The above is a bit complicated and requires understanding of how observables work.

Comment: I actually copied directly from the repo and ended up using the helper service. It is hanging on `const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);`

Comment: Any idea why that may be occuring?

Comment: Any chance you may have a few minutes to chat on your Slack channel?

Comment: the Injector is for dependency injection, I used it to avoid the cyclic dependency error in Angular. It is the equivalent of injecting it at the constructor. Unless I can see your code, I might not be able to be much of help.

Comment: Yeah, Let me open the open. Not sure why it doesn't start with my PC.